# User input is undefined when passed as a prop value. Can anyone suggest edits?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-forms

I took user input from a form.js file.

```
import React, {Component } from 'react'
class FormsAndInputs extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            organismName: ''
        }
    }

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const data = this.state
    console.log(data)
}
handleInputChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name] : event.target.value
    })
}
render () {
    const {organismName} = this.state
    return(
        <div>
           <h1> Enter the Organism ID</h1>
            <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>
        <p> <input type='text' placeholder ='Enter Organism ID'
            name='organismName' onChange = {this.handleInputChange} />
        </p>
        <p><button>Submit Data</button></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}}
export default FormsAndInputs;
```

I want to pass this `input` (stored in a constant called `organismName`) as a `props` value in another file `Nav.js` like so:

```
import FormsAndInputs from './form';
  
function NAV() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/jbrowse/jbrowse' render={(props) => <View {...props} id={FormsAndInputs.data} />} />
```

The View function is defined in another file called `Nav.js`. These are the places where the `prop` values will be passed:

```
   function View(props) {

  const fasta= require(`../genome_data/${props.id}.fna`)  
  const fai= require(`../genome_data/${props.id}.fna.fai`)
  const gff= require("../genome_data/Phyag_NZFS3770_genbank.sorted.gff.gz")
  const gfftbi = require("../genome_data/Phyag_NZFS3770_genbank.sorted.gff.gz.tbi")
  const ssrbw = require(`../genome_data/${props.id}.bw`)
```

So what's happening is the props value serves as the basename to open multiple files having same basename but different extensions.
But on rendering it is showing that the value is undefined
×
Error: Cannot find module './undefined.fna'.
Can anyone tell me how this error arose? Thank you.

Comment: What do you suppose `FormsAndInputs.data` to be?

Comment: Where is `FormsAndInputs` rendered? If you are also wanting to navigate to the `View` component on the `'/jbrowse/jbrowse'` path then you can pass the form data in route state.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to access a variable (`data`) of a class component. You should define a Context that handles the state of the organism ID in the application and retrieve that data in the `View` component.

Comment: FormsAndInputs is rendered in the App.js file. Okay I will try all these suggestions and get back to you guys. Thanks a lot for your help